# Error loading view with DBML as model using razor engine

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I have three projects in my solution:

1. Domain layer
2. GUI
3. MVC application

Now my Domain layer i have created a *.DBML (SQL to LINQ), and i want to reuse this class in my MVC application. The DBML Class has the namespace `CatalogDb` and the Domain layer has the namespace `Catalog`. This is not really a problem at the moment. In my view i have written following on the top:

`@model CatalogDb.BookMedia`

The autocompleter can also see this namespace and class without problems.

But when i run the project the view gives an error:

`Compiler Error Message: CS0246: The type or namespace name 'CatalogDb' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly?).`

Do i need to add the `CatalogDb` namespace manually in the MVC application project? I dont understand why i cant point it to the namespace which it suggests.

[image]
[image]

EDIT:

I have Catalog in my references in MVC application.

Comment: Add a reference to the Domain project in your MVC project.

Comment: @user1166147, i already have a reference to Catalog.

Comment: DomainLayer and the MVCApplication are in the same namespace? otherwise you must specify the entire namespace in the view

Comment: @Zachdev, im not quite sure what that means. But all three projects are in the same Solution. Not the same namespace. MVC application has its own namespace. Can i change the default namespace of MVC application to Catalog without destroying anything and solving the problem?

Comment: @Zachdev, can i specify two namespaces? Catalog.CatalogDb.BookMedia ?

Comment: ok, let's make a example:
MVCApplication -> default Namespace: MVCApplication
DomainLayer -> default Namespace: DomainLayer
so, my context is under DomainLayer.CatalogDB namespace then in the view I must specify `@model DomainLayer.CatalogDB.BookMedia`
check it out your classview

Comment: @Zachdev, i tried the @model Catalog.CatalogDb.BookMedia but instead it complains `Compiler Error Message: CS0246: The type or namespace name 'Catalog' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)`

Comment: show me the entire namespace of projects who appear in the ClassView

Comment: @Zachdev, can i create a Class View for the entire solution? As fare as i can see i can only create for each project.

Comment: @Zachdev, i have added two images.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/12202/discussion-between-zach-dev-and-javacake)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some hours of struggle i ended up adding af seperate *.dbml file to my MVC application and it solved the problems. I assume the namespaces were the primary cause of problem.